# When to use -ion or -ing?

Tags: verbs, nouns, gerunds

Some examples:

1. This enables the modification of files
2. This enables the modifying of files
3. This enables the edition of files
4. This enables the editing of files
5. This enables the creation of files
6. This enables the creating of files
7. This enables the deletion of files
8. This enables the deleting of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modify, create and delete, the meanings of -ion (noun) and -ing (gerundive/verbal noun thingumajig) are very similar: both relate to the action of doing something.  In this sentence I would favour the -ion option. [editing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edit?q=editing) and [edition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edition) have different meanings: editing is the only valid meaning in this context.

It's worth considering making a compound noun rather than the "the..of" construction: it's two words shorter, and in my opinion clearer.

> This enables file modification.
>
> This enables file editing.

Comment: Thanks and this is why I hate form changing languages: always special cases that do not follow any rules.

Comment: Arguably, in a non form changing language, every word is a special case :-).

Comment: Surprisingly I agree and like their honesty better than being hypocritical :)